# Placing an element exactly below another one on WP8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to place a GRID element just below another GRID element using XAML just like Android's [layout below](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_below). How can it be done, if possible?

Comment: Can we see your code that you have tried and where you've failed?

Comment: @Bob. I've actually tried no code since I didn't come up with an approach for that, yet. Is there any similar thing to Android's `layout_below` in WP8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
<StackPanel>
   <Grid/>
   <Grid/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I guess I should be spending more time at the basics of XAML, since I remmber reading about it... Thanks, made my day :)

Comment: No worries, we've all been there... Cheers